# Problem communicating with 3rd party apps via VBA on Mac M1

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word, applescript

I have created a VBA add-in for Microsoft Word. Both a Windows and Mac version. The add-in communicates with 3rd party apps.
This has worked fine for years. I'm now struggling making this work for the Mac-version with M1-based macs (Maybe also Big Sur related).
The communication works partly via a dylib written i c, via stdin and stdout.
Secondly some functions use AppleScriptTask.
I can't make either of these two methods work.

AppleScriptTask always return the error:

> Run-time error '5' 
> Invalid procedure call or argument

VBA-code:
`s = AppleScriptTask("WMscript.scpt","Test","")`

I tried scripts with .scpt, .scptd and .applescript. 
Also newly created scriptfiles with simple test.script:

```
on Test(paramS)
    tell application "Finder"
         activate
    end tell
end Test
```

The api works in other applications, but I can't open 3rd party apps in it when used from VBA.

I use these special folders for the all the 3rd party files to circumvent sandboxing for both methods:
/Library/Application support/Microsoft/Office365/User Content/Add-ins/
~/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.word/
~/Library/containers/com.microsoft.word/Data/

I also tried the *GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(FileArray)* function. It always returns 'True' regardless which filenames are sendt in the array. It never prompt the user.

**Running:**
M1 Mac
Big sur 11.6 (M1)
Microsoft Word for Mac 16.54 (21101001)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ApplceScriptTask problem was related to an incorrect path, for the script file:
Incorrect: ~/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.word/
Correct: ~/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.***W***ord/

Had to be Uppercase W.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure following will help you.

If your third-party application is from unknown developer, then it goes to GateKeeper quarantine. Try to remove quarantine before calling your VBA script, running following script.

```
set theApp to application id "Avidemux.org" -- EDIT here the bundle ID
set quotedPath to quoted form of (POSIX path of (path to theApp))
do shell script "xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine " & ¬
    quotedPath with administrator privileges
```

You can include the code above to beginning of your VBA script.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. 
It should not affect the test with AppleScript as it just activates Finder. I did test your suggestion with the api. But no change here either.

Comment: Once upon a time, I wrote VBA programs for Excel. Much has now been forgotten. I even forgot what add-ins are, so I can't help it. But as you say, everything worked for you before. Therefore, I recommend temporarily turning off System Integrity Protection (SIP) on your computer and testing the add-ins. If your add-ins work, then it's logical to assume that the current failures are due to changes in security policy. For example, in prohibiting add-ins from sending Apple events.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know you could do that.
Same problem though.If anybody has AppleScriptTask running on M1-processors I would like to know.